# Is providing a user login a functional requirement of a system?

Tags: security, requirements, login, functional-requirements

Is providing a user login a non functional requirement?

Since this is concerned with security which is a non functional requirement, I feel that providing a user login is also non functional but again I feel that it is functional.

Comment: "Providing user login" is probably too vague and broad to be a "requirement" of any kind. I would think it encompasses many functional requirements such as going through a login page then letting you buy stuff and many non-functional requirements such as no user should be able to login as any other user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User logins are more of a "feature" than a "requirement."

If you said "System shall block user from access to [some area of the system] if they are not logged in," or "System shall block user from access to [some area of the system] if they don't have the necessary security credentials," then it would be a functional requirement.

Requirements should always be accompanied by a test that, when executed, constitutes proof to the stakeholders that a requirement has been met.  Otherwise, it's not a requirement.  "System shall have user logins" is not a requirement, because you can merely have user and password fields on some form and call it a login system.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. If I go by your definition I do not see a problem at all in verifying whether the requirement has been met. You may need another requirement to make it useful, like stating user credentials must be available before allowing some action, the login as such would still be a requirement. This looks like a good source explaining the difference: https://www.guru99.com/functional-vs-non-functional-requirements.html

Comment: @MartinMaat: My answer is not about the difference between functional and non-functional requirements; a login is clearly a *functional* requirement. I suppose you could have a "requirement" that, in isolation, is not particularly useful, but requirements are typically more concrete than this.  "System shall have a login capability" is a feature or a wish, not a requirement; it lacks sufficient detail to be *meaningfully* tested in a requirements context.

Answer (score 3):

A login is a function or specific behavior.  You either have a login capability or you don't.  As such, as requirement, it would be a functional requirement.

Performance, say, of login, is a non-functional requirement: a judgement of the quality of the implementation (rather than a feature is present/absent).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement

Answer (score 0):

Security is a non-functional requirement as it is well known to everyone. Log-in is one way to achieve security .. so it is non-functional requirement.

Answer (score -2):

Providing a User login is a feature. Functional requirement herein could be  that the system must generate a temporary login and password for each user

Comment: Whether it is a feature or not is independent of the question functional vs non-functional. In this case it is a function that needs to be performed, not just a rule.